# Rails: radio buttons based on enum disappear from the form after validation errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following enum inside the Item.rb model

```
enum pricing_option: { "Fixed amount": "1", "Hourly rate": "2" }
validates :pricing_option, :inclusion => { :in => Item.pricing_options.keys }
```

As you can see I'm trying to validate the enum as well.

I have the collection radio buttons inside this form:

```
<%= form_for(@item, url: items_create_path, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |form| %>
<%= form.text_field :title, id: :item_title, autofocus: true %>
<%= collection_radio_buttons(:item, :pricing_option, Item.pricing_options, :first, :first)%>
<%= form.text_field :price, id: :item_price %>
<%= form.text_area :description, id: :item_description %>
<%= form.submit "Submit", :class=>"btn btn-default" %>
```

Everything works well except when the validations errors appear after a submit the radio buttons disappear from the form. Also the validation for the radio buttons doesn't appear.

styling for the buttons:

```
input[type="radio"]
  display: none
  margin: 40px

input[type="radio"] + label
  border: .5px solid #969696
  //border-radius: 3px
  //margin-left: 5px
  font-size: 12px
  color: #969696
  padding-bottom: 3px
  padding-top: 3px
  padding-left: 5px
  padding-right: 5px
  float: right

input[type="radio"] + label:hover
  cursor: pointer
  background-color: #f2f2f2
  border-color: #000000
  color: #3d3d3d
  //border: inset 1px

input[type="radio"]:checked + label
  background-color: #f2f2f2
  border-color: #000000
  color: #3d3d3d
  //border: inset 1px
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px #c1c1c1
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px #c1c1c1
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px #c1c1c1
```

Any idea why this happening? And how can I show the enum validation too?

Comment: Are the radio buttons being rendered and hidden or not even being rendered? inspect the HTML, maybe some CSS is hiding them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @arieljuod . The buttons are showing initially and when I submit the form correctly without any validation errors, then the form along with the buttons value gets submitted correctly. If there is a validations error, the form gets rendered again but the buttons don't show anymore. I added the css styling to my question so you can review it. This is weird, any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: According to this GitHub issue, enums are only designed for internal use: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13971. It is mentioned that quite a few things are missing to make them work properly in user-facing interfaces, one of which being form helpers. I could imagine that this is causing your problem...

Comment: @Dev you are not answering if the HTML has the RADIO tags and are hidden or the RADIO tags are not even there. I understand that they "are not show anymore" but "not show" and "doesn't appear" are ambiguous, there's a big difference between being rendered on the HTML but hidden, and not even being rendered on the HTML code. Anyway, you have `input[type="radio"] display: none`, you should clarify on your question that you are hiding the radios explicitly and using some custom radio buttons. Start by removing that CSS first to debug your problem and check the browser dev tools.